# Импорт готовой БД в android приложение

Tags: android, sqlite

Как правильно импортировать готовую БД в android приложение? Делаю через xml, парсю xml и вставляю записи в таблицу, на это уходит около 3 минут. Есть более оптимальные решения?

Comment: а есть сам файл .db базы? или только xml?

Answer (score 3):

Наверное [это (Android: simple export and import of sqlite database)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6542214) вам подойдет!